# Add text to Video for specific time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, catextlayer

I am creating a video based application where I have to select any video from local gallery and have to add a text using CATextLayer over the Video. For this I am using below code:

```
- (void) createWatermark:(UIImage*)image video:(NSURL*)videoURL
{
    if (videoURL == nil)
        return;

    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack* compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack* clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
                                   ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
                                    atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    //  create the layer with the watermark image
    CALayer* aLayer = [CALayer layer];
    aLayer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    aLayer.opacity = 0.9;

    //sorts the layer in proper order

    AVAssetTrack* videoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGSize videoSize = [videoTrack naturalSize];
    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    [parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];


    // create text Layer
    CATextLayer* titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    titleLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    titleLayer.string = @"Dummy text";
    titleLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain(@"Helvetica");
    titleLayer.fontSize = 28;
    titleLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    titleLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, videoSize.width, videoSize.height / 6);

    [parentLayer addSublayer:titleLayer];

    //create the composition and add the instructions to insert the layer:

    AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
    videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    /// instruction
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction* instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
    AVAssetTrack* mixVideoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:mixVideoTrack];
    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
    videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    // export video

    _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    _assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;

    NSLog (@"created exporter. supportedFileTypes: %@", _assetExport.supportedFileTypes);

    NSString* videoName = @"NewWatermarkedVideo.mov";

    NSString* exportPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
    NSURL* exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath error:nil];

    _assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    _assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;
    _assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

    [_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(void ) {

         //Final code here

         switch (_assetExport.status)
         {
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown:
                 NSLog(@"Unknown");
                 break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
                 NSLog(@"Waiting");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
                 NSLog(@"Exporting");
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                 NSLog(@"Created new water mark image");
                 _playButton.hidden = NO;
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                 NSLog(@"Failed- %@", _assetExport.error);
                 break;
             case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                 NSLog(@"Cancelled");
                 break;
            }
     }
     ];   
}
```

Using above code, I can able to set a text over my video. But now I have to give either FadeIN/Fade Out animation on CATextLayer OR to display moving text on Video. Please advise me. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use CAKeyframeAnimation class declared in core animation framework.

for example:

```
//start from zero opacity
titleLayer.opacity = 0;

CAKeyframeAnimation *fadeInAndOut = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeInAndOut.duration = 5.0; //5 seconds will be your fade in fade out animation.
fadeInAndOut.autoreverses = NO;
// from 0.0 * animDuration time to 0.2 * animDuration time your animation will animate opacity from zero to 1.0.
// from 0.2 * animDuration time to 0.8 * animDuration time your opacity will be 1.0 
// from 0.8 * animDuration time to 1.0 * animDuration time your animation will animate opacity from 1.0 opacity to zero.
fadeInAndOut.keyTimes = @[@(0.0), @(0.2), @(0.8), @(1.0)];
fadeInAndOut.values = @[@(0.0), @(1.0), @(1.0), @(0.0)];
fadeInAndOut.beginTime = 1.0;
fadeInAndOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;
fadeInAndOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
[titleLayer addAnimation:fadeInAndOut forKey:nil];
```

I hope it's clear for you. using same way you can animate your label position.

**UPDATE**

for animate position try this

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *fadeInAndOut = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
fadeInAndOut.duration = 5.0;
fadeInAndOut.autoreverses = NO;
fadeInAndOut.keyTimes = @[@(0.0), @(0.2), @(0.8), @(1.0)];

fadeInAndOut.values = @[[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(20, 40)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 40)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(200, 40)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(400, 40)]];
fadeInAndOut.beginTime = 1.0;
fadeInAndOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;
fadeInAndOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
[titleLayer addAnimation:fadeInAndOut forKey:nil];
```

I hardcoded points for explain purpose. you can calculate points and animation duration yourself.

Comment: Great worked, Please help me in a little issue. Can possible to animate a text over the video also?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean: Is it possible to move a text label over Video from left and when it comes to center it should wait for a second and then again move to right and then hide.

Comment: You are awesome :)

Comment: I noticed one thing, moving text label is not hiding after reaching to the right position. It stops moving and coming to Video in the right side of video.

Comment: You can adjust it using animation duration.

Comment: @Jabsonplease look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017511/how-to-add-watermark-on-final-video-after-merging-video-and-audio-asset-into-one

Comment: Hi Jabson, you there?

Comment: I am getting issue, possible for you to look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51419495/fade-effect-is-not-working-between-videos-while-merging-in-swift3-ios . Thank you

Comment: it possible to particular video  time animation add  animation show  and hide, like video duration 0.5 sec at time 0.2 sec show sticker then 0.3 sec sticker not showing ,particular time duration add and remove animation text sticker ...

Answer (score 0):

First add parent layer:

```
let parentLayer = CALayer()
```

After that add overlayer for adding fade animation:

```
let overlayLayer = CALayer()
```

And call extension for adding fade animation:

```
overlayLayer.addFadeAnimationWithTime(showTime: startTime, endTime: endTime)
```

And add this to parent layer:

```
parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)
```

Extension for fade animation with startTime and endTime:

```
extension CALayer {
func addFadeAnimationWithTime(showTime:CGFloat, endTime:CGFloat) {
    let fadeInAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
    fadeInAnimation.duration = 1
    fadeInAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0)
    fadeInAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
    fadeInAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    fadeInAnimation.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(showTime)
    fadeInAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.backwards

    self.add(fadeInAnimation, forKey: "fadeIn")

    if endTime > 0 {
        let fadeOutAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeOutAnimation.duration = 1
        fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
        fadeOutAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 0)
        fadeOutAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        fadeOutAnimation.beginTime = CFTimeInterval(endTime)
        fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards

        self.add(fadeOutAnimation, forKey: "fadeOut")
    }
}
```

}